# Are the poles on the rocker switch placed correctly?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, toggle-switch

This is a Marquardt rocker switch that worked at first. But the parts where spring all over the floor, then put together again. Now, the switch is no longer functioning. When the wattmeter was used to check the poles, there was no power contact on the top pole (image top), while the bottom pole did show power.
[image: side view][image: rocker switch]

[image: inside]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the side view and that of the toggle actuator. Why do you suspect that they might be wrong? Is it new? Did it ever work? Did you spring the parts all over the floor?